# Why do we need "never" for transparent huge pages?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Transparent huge pages (THP) can be `always`, `madvise` and `never`.

I see that most database tutorials suggest using `never` for valid reasons. However, why do we need the `never` option at all if programs can just leverage `madvise` to opt in?